# How can you use math.random() in javascript to make a rainfall effect?

Tags: jquery, html

I know there are many plug-ins that can create snow fall on your webpage, but I'd rather do it myself to learn it. I was wondering if I could use math.random() to give my image of water drops random coordinates on the page. I'm just not really sure where to start. Does anyone have any ideas how this would work?

Comment: Have you tried creating  NON random water drops?   First do that and show your work and someone can help you with randomizing it.  This as it stands is a "please do my work for me" question, which will probably get you a negative mark.

Comment: In addition to what @AhmedMasud said, provide an example of what you are trying to do.  It isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use math.random() to generate coordinate pairs for the raindrops. You could use a loop to generate any specified number of coordinate pairs and then store those coordinates in arrays for later use.